# Rigorous book for multivariable concepts

Tags: references, multicollinearity, heteroscedasticity, endogeneity, exogeneity

I am looking for a rigorous book that clearly defines and explains terms such as ‘endogenous variable’, ‘exogenous variable’, ‘multicollinearity’, ‘heteroscedasticity’ and other such terms whose names I don’t even know. I am NOT looking for an encyclopaedia, I am looking for a rigorous treatment that starts from the beginning and builds the theory while explaining all the terms along the way. I don’t mind if the book is a bit dated, or if multiple books cover this.

Comment: Pick up any undergraduate level econometrics book like Greene; Gujarati; Davidson, Mackinnon etc.

Comment: I second @User1865345, these are mostly terms used in econometrics, and any good econometrics book will do.

Comment: Searching on [this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=book+wiki%3Ayes+econom%2A+regression) you can find useful resources.

Comment: But surely these terms must originate in some rigorous treatment from where they are borrowed in econometrics?

Comment: It is known that _heteroscedasticity_ originated in mainstream statistics (the term was introduced by Karl Pearson),  I endorse previous commenters. No one makes nearly so much use of  the terms _endogenous_ or _exogenous_ as  econometricians. In my experience  those terms are almost never used by anybody else. As for multicollinearity, most good regression or econometrics  books explain that (1) with modern software it's not an issue (2) it is naive to expect that regressor variables in real observational data don't have some correlations with each other and you do need to think about that.